# Weak compactness of the closed unit ball of $L_{\infty}(\mu,X)$ in $L_{1}(\mu,X)$

Tags: banach-spaces

It is known that the closed unit ball of $L_{\infty}(\mu)$ is weakly compact in $L_{1}(\mu)$. A natural question arises in the case of spaces of Bochner integral functions:

Question. Let $X$ be a Banach space. In what cases the closed unit ball of $L_{\infty}(\mu,X)$ is weakly compact in $L_{1}(\mu,X)$ ?

I am not sure that this question is interesting or remains open.

Comment: Not a deep insight, but for the record: reflexivity of $X$ is certainly necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jochen commented, you need $X$ to be reflexive, and this is sufficient. It is enough to show that the unit ball of $L_\infty(X)$ is closed in the reflexive space $L_2(X)$.  But the injection from $L_\infty(X)$ into  $L_2(X)$ is the adjoint of the injection from  $L_2(X)$ into  $L_1(X)$, so this is automatic. (Recall that $L_p(X)^* = L_{p'}(X^*)$ when $X$ is reflexive and $p <\infty$. See Diestel-Uhl section IV.1.)

Comment: Thanks, Bill. You are right.